# What is the correct terminology for games like Final Fantasy (the early ones)

Tags: terminology, final-fantasy-series

Is there a trade industry term to refer to games with feel and gameplay like "Final Fantasy IV" etc...?

I would like to search for similar games (especially if, ideally, a good open source ones exist), but having trouble with proper genre for search terms. Wiki simply dubs them "role playing games" which is very vague as far as searching.

Comment: The correct term is, JRPG.  They've changed over the years, but that's essentially what they are.

Comment: I wish more games came out like the classic Final Fantasy games 1-6.

Comment: Pretty sure it's either 'Role Playing Game' or 'Adventure Game'.  Not sure what it has to do with being Japanese.

Comment: Are we disallowing terminology questions now?

Comment: @Fluttershy If you see his comments [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95930/what-is-the-correct-terminology-for-games-like-final-fantasy-original-ones#comment131215_95933), it would appear what he's really looking for is a game recommendation question.

Comment: @Wipqozn Touché, good sir.

Comment: @Wipqozn - if you bother reading, you will see I'm really looking for a GENRE NAME to google on, not specific game recommendations.

Comment: @DVK I did read, which is what gave me this impression. Your responses and question gave me the impression you're just looking for a list of games, which would be off-topic. However, I think I was hasty in my decision to cast a close vote since your question is fine in it's current form.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the most part, RPG is the main classification. Some might also opt to say JRPG, or "Japanese RPG", meaning to distinguish this narrative-style from the more open-ended style of western RPGs such as Fallout.

Past that, it's pretty rough and there probably isn't a specific terminology. Genres are kinda broad by nature and it's by tagging a ton of extra labels on top of it that specificity is found. For example, the descriptors for the early Final Fantasy games will generally be "turn based" and "menu driven" party combat in an "overworld exploration" RPG.

If you want to narrow it down to the essence specifically of the full combination brought by Final Fantasy, I think there isn't really any general term so much as a "likening". That is, you'd call a game of similar substance as "a turn-based menu-driven RPG like the Final Fantasy series". This is kinda like how [Etrian Odyssey](http://www.atlus.com/etrian/) had been marketed as an "old-fashioned first-person dungeon RPG like the Wizardry games". First-person dungeon RPG isn't the most descriptive, but it kinda fits those games to a T and "Wizardry-like" never really took off quite like "roguelike" did.

Past this, there really isn't a unique terminology for these games. Early SaGa games, early Final Fantasy, Dragon Quest... RPG has pretty much been the identifying term for them since very early on, and little has changed in that department.

Comment: +1 and accept for "menu driven" and "overworld exploration". That was the terms that I was mainly missing. Thx

Comment: There are [two](http://penny-arcade.com/patv/episode/western-japanese-rpgs-part-1) [episodes](http://penny-arcade.com/patv/episode/western-japanese-rpgs-part-2) from [Extra Credits](http://extra-credits.net/) where they argue that (western) RPGs and (asian, not necessarily Japanese) JRPGs are two quite distinct genres that just share a set of mechanics.

Comment: I wonder if in Japan they call their them JRPG... Perhaps JRPGs are  called RPGs and "Occidental" one are called ORPG there :D

Answer (score 4):

The name used in the industry is Role-Playing game, but they are commonly referred to as "Japanese Roleplaying Games" (JRPG) within the gaming community. [Eastern RPG](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EasternRPG) is another commonly used term, but it's not as widespread as JRPG.

Comment: Sorry, but RPGs are extremely varied. I specifically was looking for games with similar feel and gameplay mechanics to FF.

Comment: @DVK In that case your question appears to be off-topic. We don't allow game recommendation questions on Arqade, which seems to be what you're asking.

Comment: I asked for what to call them, not examples of them. JRPG may work, but RPG is definitely wrong (too generic)

Comment: @DVK As I stated in my answer, RPG is the term used by the *industry*, but not the community at large. What you're looking for is JRPG, or Eastern RPG.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, a more specific term doesn't exist besides JRPG. A lot of gaming personas and shows have mentioned that fundamentally our game genres are not of any use. I could write out the entire the reasoning and logic but I'm not nearly qualified enough. Which is why it's a good thing someone else has done this already:

http://penny-arcade.com/patv/episode/western-japanese-rpgs-part-1

In regards to this question I'd say the most relevant part is pointing out how our genre definitions are incorrect (Around 2:30 minutes). The reasoning is that we define based on systems and surface elements and core reasons for playing.

So honestly, the answer to your question is, there isn't really a current term for those exact sorts of games. We can list aspects but the whole or niche they play is difficult to define. At the moment I would suggest turning your search into "16 Bit JRPGs" if you want to catch a lot of them.